# Можно ли вместо floor использовать round?

Tags: javascript

В Получение случайного целого числа между двумя значениями включительно?

```js
function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min); // The maximum is inclusive and the minimum is inclusive
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141742/discussion-on-question-by-b-dec-b----floor--round).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашей конкретной задаче метод round даст распределение вероятности на краях в 2 раза меньше чем в середине.

То есть при такой `getRandomIntInclusive(1,6)` - `1` и `6` будут выпадать в `2` раза реже чем `2`,`3`,`4`,`5`

Метод floor дает в минимуме такую же вероятность что и в середине, но нулевую вероятность в максимуме (которая легко исправляется через +1).

*Дальше офтопик*

Согласен с @wololo по поводу того что метод исправления инклюзивности максимума может давать сбой, хоть и с малой вероятностью

Один из способов использовать вместо +1 очень близкое к 1 число.

```
+ 1 - Number.EPSILON
```

А лучше

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) * (1 - Number.EPSILON) ) + min
```

Хотя проще

```
 if ( rand_val > max ) return max;
 return rand_val
```

Comment: `А лучше + 1 - Number.EPSILON`. Хитро. Но этого не достаточно, например, при `min = 10` и `max = 20`.

Comment: тогда остается вынести его за скобки..

Comment: но тогда минимум ломается...

Comment: Вычитать эпсилон не надо если IEEE-754. `Math.random() < 1`. Можно показать что `Math.random() * n < n` для целого `n`. Значит после `Math.floor` будет верный диапазон. Формула должна быть `Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min`. `min` вне скобок - это важно.

Comment: @wololo теперь уж точно пофиксил) думаю не  страшно что у максимума вероятност будет 99.99999999999999% / (max-min)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, а я и не предлагал вычитать эпсилон.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy  тут @wololo утверждает что есть вероятность что Math.random() вернет число больше чем `1-Number.EPSILON`

Answer (score -2):

[Вот](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_math.asp) вам документация по классу Math;
[Вот](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) вам документация по методу Round. Round - Округляет значение до ближайшего целого или указанного количества десятичных знаков;
[Вот](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) вам документация по методу Ceil. Ceil - Возвращает наименьшее целое число, которое больше или равно указанному числу;
[Вот](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) вам документация по методу Floor. Floor - Возвращает наибольшее целое число, которое меньше или равно указанному числу;

Можно ли вместо floor использовать round? Судя по вашему вопросу, вам можно использовать обычный Round. Или вообще любой из этих методов, т.к. ни один из них не сможет пересечь ни одну из границ рандома.

UPD: поменял ссылки, не посмотрел, что этот вопрос по JS

Comment: не ответ. и тут вы немного не правы.

Comment: @eri , почему я не прав?

Comment: самое главное - разное распределение вероятности, а про пересечение границы писал wololo

Comment: @eri, тогда можно использовать обычный round

Comment: почему можно? он же работает совсем по другому и проблемы